# Is it possible to pass command line arguments when running Haskell code with `ghc -e`?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Intuitively, I've tried

```
$ ghc -e "import System.Environment" -e "getArgs" -- a b c
ghc: unrecognised flag: --
did you mean one of:
  -n
  -F
  -v

Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
$
```

...without success.

I was expecting the output to be along the lines of `["a","b","c"]`.

[The docs here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/using.html#expression-evaluation-mode) don't seem to mention any way to pass cli arguments through.

AFAIK piping in stdio works as expected.

And perhaps if it is not possible to pass in arguments with `ghc -e`, maybe it's still possible with `ghci` to supply both some code, some arguments to it, run, then exit?

Comment: If there is no way, and you can think of one that work well, you should propose it to GHC, either on https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ or maybe via a GHC proposal at https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/

Comment: The best I can do: `ghc -e "import System.Environment" -e ":set args a b c" -e "getArgs"`

Comment: @chi I like your comment's direction. Maybe a shell function could be defined along those lines. I've started to fiddle with putting one together.

Comment: This is as far as I got so far: `function ghce () { echo "$1" | xargs ghc -e ":set args ${@:2}" }; ghce '-e "import System.Environment" -e "getArgs"' "1 2 3"`
`["1","2","3"]`. Which is incorrect, since its output should be `["1 2 3"]`, and not need quotes: `"1 2 3"` -> `1 2 3`. And I would like if it also handled `1 '2 3' 4` as `["1","2 3","4"]`, but at this point I get `target ‘2 3’ is not a module name or a source file` error. Not sure why.

Comment: I guess the issue here is the missing escaping. One would need `ghc -e ":set args \"1 2 3\"" -e "getArgs" ` which might be tricky to obtain in the shell (?). I'm pretty sure there is a way, but my bash-fu is not so advanced. Superuser.SE surely knows.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of the question:

```
Prelude> :help :main
 Commands available from the prompt: 
   …
   :main [<arguments> ...]     run the main function with the given arguments
   …
Prelude> let main = System.Environment.getArgs >>= print
Prelude> :main foo bar
["foo","bar"]
```